# Gaussian approximation of Poisson distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I am using a Gaussian distribution to generate a Poisson variable with parameter $\lambda$. According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution#Related_distributions), when $\lambda > 1000$ this approximation is pretty good. However, using MATLAB I noticed that even when $\lambda = 400$ Gaussian and Poisson distributions seem to be almost identical.
What do you think would be the minimum value of $\lambda$ to guarantee that the two distributions are close enough?

Comment: "What do you think would be the minimum value of $\lambda$ to guarantee that the two distributions are close enough?" - most likely it depends on the computing environment...

Comment: And it also depends on what "close enough" means to you.

Comment: I do not have any specific definition of closeness per se, but the value given on wikipedia has no justification either. I am simply looking for something that makes sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [this](http://www.johndcook.com/normal_approx_to_poisson.html), in particular the section "General bound on error".

The article was written by user [John D. Cook](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/247/john-d-cook).